# Share link in facebook post

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-sharer

i have this simple php code to post message on the facebook wall

```
require_once('facebook.php');

try {
    $facebook = new Facebook(FB_APIKEY, FB_SECRET);

    $facebook->api_client->session_key = FB_SESSION;

    $attachment = array(
        'message' => 'some meesgae',
        'name' => 'This is my demo Facebook application!',
        'caption' => "Caption of the Post",
        'link' => 'mylink.com',
        'description' => 'this is a description',
        'actions' => array(array(
                     'name' => 'Get Search', 
                     'link' => 'google.com'
                  ))
    );

    $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed?access_token=' . FB_SESSION, 
              'post', 
              $attachment);

     var_dump($result);
```

But i cant see any  **share** link appears on the post on the FB wall.

Can anyone tell me how to add the **share** link on my post in FB wall
Thanks

Comment: Did you try with facebook sharer:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/

Sharer is good if you want to publish something on user's wall not really for publishing on your own wall but you can try with this. Posts published with "FB sharer" has "share" link bellow the post. You can also attach a thumbnail, link etc. Read more on URL above.

Comment: For what it's worth, it looks like you're using an old version of the Facebook PHP SDK - you might want to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

i have a question, did you figure out how to do this?
when posting just a staus without image or link i see the share link on the post but when sending image or link it isn't, 
i found a solution for link by puting it inside the message but still have the problem with image.

for the link you can use :

```
$attachment = array(
  'access_token'  => $page_info['access_token'],
  'message'       => "some text here \n\n {mylinkpersonal}"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Jimmy Sawczuk commented you seem to use an old version of the Facebook PHP SDK, you should update to the [latest version](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk).

Another thing it's that I don't think you need to specify an `access token` when using the PHP SDK.

```
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST', $attachment);
```

There is an example in the Facebook documentation on how to "[Post a link to a User's wall using the Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/)".